# MySQL CLustering Options

Tags: mysql, master-slave-replication, ndbcluster, mysql-innodb-cluster

I have two **MySQL Database Servers** i.e.
One is **Active Server --> Master** and second is **Passive Server --> Slave.**

And as we know we have 3-4 MySQL **HR,DR Solutions / Clustering options**.For example

01 : MySQL NDB Cluster

02 : MySQL InnoDB Cluster

03 : MySQL Cluster Carrier Grade

**My First Question** is i want to deploy **One Active & One Passive** MySQL Server so which **Cluster Option / HA,DR Option** will be fit for above mentioned scenario ?

**My Second Question** is suppose i have deploy **One Active & One Passive MySQL Server** in any above mentioned **Cluster Option / HA,DR Option**. So what about licensing ? I have to buy license of MySQL Servers/ Cluster ?

Regards,

Mubashar Iftikhar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two servers cannot give you as much HA as three.  And the three need to be geographically spread across 3 data centers.  That way, if a datacenter fails (and they do), the other two have a quorum and can continue running.

If you have already implemented your application using InnoDB, then the simplest is to go with 02: InnoDB Cluster.  Yes, it can have one active and multiple passive nodes.  I don't think there are $$ licenses for 01 and 02.

Another option is (again, no $$ license) is to have 3+ servers using InnoDB, plus Galera's clustering solution.  (Or MariaDB, which has Galera builtin.)

Comment: you want to say that for One Master & One Slave (Including 3rd Server) MySQL InnoDB Cluster is the best option for HA/Clustering ? 
Second thing can you please share with me any reference related Pros & Cons of all three above mentioned HA/DR Clustering solutions ???

Comment: This is a requirement from client side and he wants only one master and one slave for HA solution & for that i was confused which (NDB, InnoDB, Cluster Carrier Grade ) will be best for that scenario

Comment: REPEATING ---> If i use Three Servers including (One Master & One Slave). & MySQL InnoDB for HA/Clustering that can full fill my requirements or not ?
Kindly clear this thing again. 
By the way thanks for your response. Your response is very help full for me

Comment: @MubasharIftikhar - I'm confused:  With 1 Master and 1 Slave, what is the 3rd Server?  If it is another Master or Slave, then any of the solutions is an HA solution.  Keep in mind that InnoDB Cluster is based on InnoDB; the other two are based on NDB.  There are differences in the SQL.

Comment: okay dear i understand, but in simple & short words , if we have a setup of master slave replication then MySQL InnoDB Cluster is fit for that scenario ?

Comment: and if we can not use MySQL NDB Cluster then what is the reason ? i just want to make sure this concept.

Comment: @MubasharIftikhar - I'm going to change my advice.  Flip a coin to decide which way to go.  Then implement a prototype.  Meanwhile, do more research on the options you pose.  _Plus_ gain some experience with whichever approach you picked.  Plan to re-implement in a month or two.  _Without that experience, you cannot get a reliable answer now._